# Why is Pandas DataFrame index part of my queries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame called `claims`, and I want to locate the attributes of the claim with a specific `ClaimID`. I know the index of the row I want is 18504.
I've noticed the following:

```
In: print(claims.iloc[18504]['ClaimID'])
Out: 29395

In: print(claims.loc[claims['ClaimID'] == 29395]['ClaimID'])
Out: 18504    29395
```

It seems that when I use the second method, I get the index alongside the `ClaimID`. However, I only want the `ClaimID` and not the index. Can someone tell me what's going on with the second method and how I can fix it?

Comment: Where is the point of finding the `ClaimID` using the ID which is equal to the `ClaimID`? To answer your question: You can use [pandas.DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at) to get a single value instead of the index-value-pair.

Comment: `claims.loc[claims['ClaimID'] == 29395, 'ClaimID'].squeeze()`?